# Can I implement an email send-list in GSuite?

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I'm aware that I can group contacts into a label (called a group confusingly) in both gmail and GSuite, but this just expands the label into all the recipients. I'm also aware of the trick to send emails BCC'ing the label name to emulate a simple mailing list.

But does GSuite allow me to actually run a less hacky email-list, specifically to email people outside my organisation? I am wondering if Google Groups can be used for this purpose but am a bit confused how that would work; would I have to send email to the Group to get it distributed? And would this mean anyone else could do the same?

The rationale here is we have a free account for a community interest group of ~30 members and there is no budget or desire to use a paid mailing list service. But the BCC trick seems to flag some ISPs to bounce the mails.

What's the closest I can get in GSuite without substantial work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Groups, both the common Google Groups and Google Groups for Business if they are enabled for your account, could be used to create email distribution lists.

If you are the G Suite Administrator, you could create groups directly from the administration panel (admin.google.com).

Comment: Could you expand at all - I can see a way of doing it but it appears a bit clumsy and like it would create an email chat group if not done properly?